# Error running Rails Server - unable to load gem 'sass-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

I'm new to Rails and trying to load and configure it for the first time.  I'm following the instructions on http://installrails.com/steps/rails_for_linux_and_other for installing on Linux (I'm actually using an Ubuntu Virtual Machine that is installed on a Windows 10 Host).

I keep getting this error:

```
`rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::Tilt
```

There is nothing that seems to be able to tell me what to do from here.  I've actually uninstalled, and re-installed Rails once, because I thought my Rails version was creating problems (I did have **Rails 5.1.1**), but the same thing is happening now (with **Rails 4.2.6**).

Ruby Version:

```
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
```

Gem List:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.1.1)
actionmailer (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
actionpack (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
actionview (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
activejob (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
activemodel (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
activerecord (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
activesupport (5.1.1, 4.2.6)
addressable (2.5.1)
arel (8.0.0, 6.0.4)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
bindex (0.5.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.14.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
byebug (9.0.6)
capybara (2.14.0)
childprocess (0.7.0)
coffee-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
erubi (1.6.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
ffi (1.9.18)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
globalid (0.4.0)
i18n (0.8.1)
io-console (0.4.5)
jbuilder (2.6.4)
jquery-rails (4.3.1)
json (1.8.6, 1.8.3)
listen (3.1.5)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.5)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.2, 5.8.5)
multi_json (1.12.1)
mustermann (1.0.0)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.0.0)
nokogiri (1.7.2)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.1.0)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
puma (3.8.2)
rack (2.0.3, 1.6.8)
rack-protection (2.0.0)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3, 1.0.8)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (4.2.6)
rake (12.0.0, 10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.8)
rb-inotify (0.9.8)
rdoc (4.3.0, 4.2.1)
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.4.24)
sass-rails (5.0.6)
sdoc (0.4.2)
selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)
sinatra (2.0.0)
spring (2.0.1)
spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
test-unit (3.1.5)
thor (0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tilt (2.0.7)
turbolinks (5.0.1)
turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
tzinfo (1.2.3)
uglifier (3.2.0)
web-console (3.5.1, 2.3.0)
websocket (1.2.4)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out

```
gem 'sass-rails'
```

Then did a

```
bundle update
```

The server seems to work now. The only thing I'm not completely sure of is if I need that gem for something.  (Like I said, I'm new to Rails).

Answer (score 0):

try to run following command:

```
bundle update
```

If it failed then try to comment below code:

```
saas-rails

bundle install
```

Comment: I did. It's the same result.